# Layout doesn't show anything when updating from a java thread

Tags: java, android, multithreading

I am traying to make a an app, that is listening to an URL on a thread and if there is a certain file at that place, my app will show the content in a tableLayout.

I've manage to complete the first part for listening from URL, but now i can't make it show the content in layout. I recived all data from URL and also i am adding data in tableLayout correctly but still doesn't show anything.

Here what i have done.

**Listening URL Method**

```
private void createListenerURL(){

Runnable runnable=new Runnable() {
  @Override
  public void run() {
   URL url = new URL(urlPath);
   InputStream inputStream = url.openStream();

  // geting all data from URL and addig in table row like this:

     runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
        @Override
        public void run() {
         TableLayout tableLayout=(TableLayout)findViewById(R.id.tabeldisplay);

          final TableRow tr=new TableRow(this);
           tr.setId(i);
           tr.setLayoutParams(new TableRow.LayoutParams(TableRow.LayoutParams.FILL_PARENT,TableRow.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT));

            TextView textview=new TextView(this);
            textview.setLayoutParams(new TableRow.LayoutParams(TableRow.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT,TableRow.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT));
            textview.setText(data.getProductName().get(i));
            textview.setTextSize(fontSizeTabel);
            textview.setTextColor(Color.parseColor("#010101"));

        tr.addView(textview);
      tableLayout.addView(tr);
        }
    });

    // starting a listening thread

  };
    };

    Thread thread=new Thread(runnable);
    thread.start();
    while (1==1){
        try {
            thread.sleep(5000);
            thread.run();
        } catch (InterruptedException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

    }
}
```

**Main Method**

```
@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.main);
    createListenigURLThread();

}
```

Is there something wrong whit my code or i need to add something?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have manage to solve my problem. the main mistake was that i am not using the same thread, every time i am iterating I am creating a new thread.

Here is the wrighte solution.

**Listening URL Methode**

```
private void createListenerURL(){
   URL url = new URL(urlPath);
   InputStream inputStream = url.openStream();

   // geting all data from URL and addig in table row like this:

   new Thread(new Runnable() {
     @Override
     public void run() {

         while (1==1){
           try {
                runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
                    @Override
                    public void run() {
                         TableLayout tableLayout=(TableLayout)findViewById(R.id.tabeldisplay);

                         final TableRow tr=new TableRow(this);
                         tr.setId(i);
                         tr.setLayoutParams(new TableRow.LayoutParams(TableRow.LayoutParams.FILL_PARENT,TableRow.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT));

                         TextView textview=new TextView(this);
                         textview.setLayoutParams(new TableRow.LayoutParams(TableRow.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT,TableRow.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT));
                         textview.setText(data.getProductName().get(i));
                         textview.setTextSize(fontSizeTabel);
                         textview.setTextColor(Color.parseColor("#010101"));

                         tr.addView(textview);
                         tableLayout.addView(tr);
                         }
                });
              } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                 e.printStackTrace();
              }

          try {
              Thread.sleep(refreshRateURL);
              } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
              }
         }
      }).start();
 }
```

Answer (score 1):

You cannot update the Ui from a thread that is not the main thread.
use runOnUiThread(new Runnable....) to update your ui

Comment: I have tried like this also(I've edidted my post) to see how i've tried

Comment: You are setting the layoutParams to TableRow.LayoutParams.FILL_PARENT,TableRow.LayoutParams.FILL_PARENT. That means that every child will try to occupy all the space in the tablelayout. Try changing the LayoutParams and see if it works

Comment: I've even tried as you sugested , I've used WRAP_CONTENT and still doesn't show anythig.

Comment: Try setting a fixed pixel value just to be sure that's not your problem

Comment: I've done that also , but i don't think that is the problem, because my interface doesn't show anything not even the fix layout made in main.XML

Answer (score 0):

Modifying the UI is only possible from the UI thread. If you want to update it from an other thread you should use [runOnUIThread](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Activity.html#runOnUiThread%28java.lang.Runnable%29) which runs on the main thread, and can update the UI.

Answer (score 0):

Take at look at the [View](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/View.html) class's invalidate() method. It's described under the "Drawing" section.